# java.lang.IllegalStateException : Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, auth0

```java
package com.example.Aop;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTVerificationException;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.Claim;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;

@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectjClass
{
    public void verification()
    {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret");
        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).build(); //Reusable verifier instance
        DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
        Claim claim = jwt.getClaim("Authorities"); // diese Authorities ist commt aus generateToken
        List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(claim.asString().split(","));
        if (request.getMethod().equals("GET") && !asList.contains("READ"))
        {
            new Exception("you don't have read permission ");
        }
        if (request.getMethod().equals("POST") && !asList.contains("WRITE"))
        {
            new Exception("you don't have WRITE permission ");
        }

        if (request.getMethod().equals("DELETE") && !asList.contains("DELETE"))
        {
            new Exception("you don't have DELETE permission ");
        }
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.example.DB..*.*(..))")
    public void beforRepository()
    {
        try
        {
            verification();
        }
        catch (JWTVerificationException exception)
        {
            //Invalid signature/claims
        }
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.example.Autorization..*.*(..))")
    public void beforeCotroller()
    {
        try
        {
            //verification();
        }
        catch (JWTVerificationException exception)
        {
            //Invalid signature/claims
        }
    }
}
```

**please help Me to lose this issue :** No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

Comment: Your code block is unreadable please format the code with a lot less white space so that it is readable.